# uiscrollview zoom to overlay rect

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I want to tap to zoom a UIImageView and put it inside a overlay.[image]

Just like this picture.I want to put the cyan color rect to the blue one.How can I do this?

Comment: Which solution did you adopt?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple CALayers. CALayer can be overlaid easily, as you can stack sublayers